# While trying to work copy Bit16 Mat, only half of it is being actually copied

Tags: opencv, casting, mat

So I am new to OpenCV, what I want to do is to copy elements of an bit16 matrix.

```
src.create(h, w, CV_16UC(channels));
dst.create(hr, wr, CV_16UC(channels));
finalDst.create(h, w, CV_16UC(channels));
memcpy(src.data, data_in, w*h*sizeof(raw_t_ubit16));
for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < w; j++)
  {
    finalDst.data[j + i*w] = src.data[j + i*w];
  }
}
memcpy(data_out, finalDst.data, h*w*sizeof(raw_t_ubit16));
```

However this only copies one half of the image, Ironically if I put 2*h instead of h then everything gets back to normal. But that shouldn't be so, since I am defining h to be the exact height of my image just like w is the width.

Comment: and you probably should consider using `cv::copyTo(...)` or `cv::clone()`

Comment: What is raw_t_*? Are these the Image data types from Mathematica LibraryLink? ( https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

src.data - gives you (*uchar), but not (*raw_t_ubit16).

(*uchar)  8 bit.

(*raw_t_ubit16) 16 bit.

((*uchar)data)[2] - will point to 3-rd byte in array (assumes array of uchar).

((*raw_t_ubit16)data)[2] - will point to 5-th byte in array (assumes array of raw_t_ubit16).

That's why you got only a half copied.

You can write:

```
((raw_t_ubit16*)finalDst.data)[j + i*w] = ((raw_t_ubit16*)src.data)[j + i*w];
```

It should work, but better use clone() method of Mat class:

```
m1=m2.clone();
```

Comment: Tried that, while building the file I got an error saying '=' : left operand must be l-value. .Copy is not feasible for task that I am now doing. Also if in the final memcpy I specify sizeif(raw_t_ubit8) the whole image gets copied. If it was an issue with *uchar as opposed to *raw_t_ubit16 shouldn't I get complete gibberish in one half of image and lose some information on the other?

Comment: (raw_t_ubit16*)finalDst.data[j + i*w] = (raw_t_ubit16*)src.data[j + i*w];